# Configuring PHP-FPM in Apache

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, httpd

I installed **Apache/2.4.54**, **PHP72-FPM**, **PHP74-FPM** and some other versions of PHP-FPM on Arch Linux.
Apparently there is some misconfiguration in **httpd.conf**, PHP can`t interpret anything and browser comments out the code.

What I tried:

**httpd.conf:**

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp72.so
    AddHandler php72-script php
    Include conf/extra/php72-module.conf
    ...
```

**php72-module.conf:**

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    <IfModule php_module7>
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php72-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
            ...
```

*`php72-fpm is active.`*

and

`php -v` returns: *`PHP 8.1.12 (cli)`*

---

### Updated:

I moved:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php72-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
```

to `<VirtualHost>` and got `[503 Unavailable]`,

**Error log:**

```
[proxy:error] FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm72/php-fpm.sock (*:80) failed
```

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are mixing php-fpm with modphp in your configuration. The only steps you should have to do are these:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.x          # disable modphp (optional)
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork     # to use php-fpm, you need to switch to mpm_event
sudo a2enmod mpm_event        # enable mpm_event
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_fcgi # enable proxy_fcgi, required for php-fpm
sudo a2enconf php7.2-fpm      # enable php7.2-fpm
```

There is no need to update your vhosts file, unless Archlinux doesn't come with the apache helpers `a2*`.

### Update following your update

Make sure you have a unix socket at that specific location. You should probably verify in your `/etc/php/fpm/pool.d/xxx.conf` configuation the exact location of your socket and then restart php-fpm.

Comment: I enabled `mpm_event` before I try it again, got: `Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.`

Comment: @Phree You need to disable modphp alltogether (as in the first of the list of commands) - are you sure that there is not one single (version of) modphp is running?

Comment: I dont see modphp in uncommented modules in `httpd.conf` and already have commented out these lines:
`LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so   &   AddHandler php-script php
   &   Include conf/extra/php_module.conf` @zenlord

Comment: @Phree Can you try uninstalling all php***-apache packages to be sure you're not using modphp? Once modphp is disabled, you should be able to enable the mpm_event module. The Apache wiki shows how to set AddHandler to point to a unix socket: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/PHP-FPM (and if I'm not mistaken in your AddHandler line 'php-script' should be replaced with a suitable regular expression like `^/(.*\.php)$`

Comment: Rewriting `\.php$` with another regex pattern worked with `php80-fpm`. BTW I came up with `Prefork MPM` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

## For Ubuntu 20-22 users:

### Purpose:

***Install fpm with sockets + fcgid module + apply user rights on requests per domain.***

### step 1: installation

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid
sudo apt-get install php8.1-fpm

# ubuntu 20 missing libs?!
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

### step 2: disable/enable modules

```
sudo a2dismod php* mpm_prerfork cgi cgid
sudo a2enmod mpm_event fcgid proxy_fcgi headers rewrite
# Ubuntu 20
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
# Ubuntu 22
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm
```

### step 3: add configuration commands

***User: "john"***

***Domain: "mydomain.com"***

***(a). Apache FPM configuration***

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf
```

type:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 20
  AddType   application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddHandler    application/x-httpd-php .php
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

***(b). FPM configuration***

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo cp /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/mydomain.com.conf
# Ubuntu 22
sudo cp /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/mydomain.com.conf
```

change:

```
[www] -> [mydomain.com]
user = www-data -> user = john
group = www-data -> group = john
```

add or leave empty:

```
;;;;;;;;;;
; Memory ;
;;;;;;;;;;
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 12M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 12M
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 12M
;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;
php_value[user_ini.filename] = ".user.ini"
php_value[default_charset] = "UTF-8"
php_flag[short_open_tag] = Off
php_flag[display_errors] = On
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = On
php_flag[log_errors] = On
php_value[log_errors_max_len] = 1024
php_flag[report_memleaks] = On
php_flag[html_errors] = On
php_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
php_flag[file_uploads] = On
php_value[max_file_uploads] = 20
php_flag[allow_url_fopen] = On
php_flag[allow_url_include] = Off
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_flag[session.use_strict_mode] = 1
php_flag[session.use_cookies] = 1
php_flag[session.use_only_cookies] = 1
; temporary disabled fro STEP 5 system('whoami') to run!
;php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
php_admin_value[error_log] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/log/php_errors.log"
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/"
php_admin_value[doc_root] = "/var/www/mydomain.com"
php_admin_value[sys_temp_dir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/tmp"
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/tmp"
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/session"
php_admin_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/tmp"
php_admin_value[curl.cainfo] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/server/registry/cacert.pem"
```

`php_admin_value`, `php_admin_flag`: can't be changed by user

`php_value`, `php_flag`: can be changed by user

***(c). Create vhost***

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf
```

type:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com.localhost
ServerAlias mydomain.com.localhost
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidConnectTimeout 20
    AddType   application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler    application/x-httpd-php .php

    # Ubuntu 20
    ProxyPassMatch " ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.mydomain.com.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/mydomain.com/"
    # Ubuntu 22
    ProxyPassMatch " ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.mydomain.com.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/mydomain.com/"

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/>
        Options +ExecCGI
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
#        FRONT CONTROLLER PATTERN
#        RewriteEngine On
#        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/public_html/index.php"
#        RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/public_html/index.php?$1" [NC,NE,L,PT,QSA]
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

# CPU usage limits 5s 10s
RLimitCPU 5 10
# memory limits to 10M 20M
RLimitMEM 10000000 20000000
# limit of forked processes 20 30
RLimitNPROC 20 30
LogLevel warn
ErrorLogFormat connection "[%t] New connection: [%{c}L] [ip: %a]"
ErrorLogFormat request "[%t] [%{c}L] New request: [%L] [pid %P] %F: %E"
ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%{c}L] [%L] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: %M"
ErrorLog /var/www/mydomain.com/log/apache_error.log
CustomLog /var/www/mydomain.com/log/apache_access.log combined
ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

***(d). Network***

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

type(*):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com
127.0.1.1   aspire1.machine.com aspire1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

create or edit file:

```
sudo nano /etc/localhost
```

type there(*):

```
aspire1
```

(*)replace `aspire1` with any short name you like.

### step 4: load vhost

```
sudo a2ensite mydomain.conf
```

### step 5: create domain files + permissions

```
sudo mkdir -p  /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
sudo mkdir /var/www/mydomain.com/log/
sudo touch /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/info.php
sudo nano /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/info.php
```

at `info.php` type:

```
<?php

echo '<b>';
echo php_sapi_name();
echo '</b><br>';

printf("%s<br>", 'DOCUMENT_ROOT=<b>'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'</b>');

printf("%s", 'User=<b>');
system('whoami');
echo '</b><br>';

phpinfo();
```

Assign permissions:

```
sudo chown -R  john:john /var/www/mydomain.com
sudo find /var/www/mydomain.com -type d -name '*' -exec chmod 700 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/mydomain.com -type f -name '*' -exec chmod 600 {} \;
# open execute
sudo chmod 711 /var/www/mydomain.com
sudo chmod 711 /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
```

### step 6: Ignition!

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo service php7.4-fpm reload
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
# Ubuntu 22
sudo service php8.1-fpm reload
sudo service php8.1-fpm restart
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

### step 7: cockpit!

Supposing you haven't enabled `rewrite` at the vhost file, open browser and type:

```
mydomain.localhost/public_html/info.php
```

### step 8: switch Apache configuration

***Let's switch from FPM to modphp:***

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm
sudo a2enmod php7.4
# Ubuntu 22
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm
sudo a2enmod php8.1
######
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2dismod fcgid
sudo a2dismod proxy_fcgi
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

***Let's switch from modphp to FPM:***

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
sudo a2dismod php7.4
# Ubuntu 22
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm
sudo a2dismod php8.1
######
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod fcgid
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
# Ubuntu 20
sudo service php7.4-fpm reload
# Ubuntu 22
sudo service php8.1-fpm reload
######
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Good luck!

Ref.:

1. https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-and-configure-fastcgi-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04/
2. https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-and-configure-fastcgi-and-php-fpm-on-debian-10/
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029564/php-7-2-fastcgi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-server/1458664#1458664